# Curiosity about Usage of --> .this

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to Android and Java. I have some doubt on the usage of **this** in the code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Intent thePigeonsss = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
}

void attachButtonListener(Button btn, final String theString) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent thePigeon = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
          thePigeon.putExtra(theString, theString);
        }
    });
}
```

On above is some snippet of my code. What I don't understand about is the Intent constructor in the `attachButtonListener`. There is some error in the intent constructor and the reason is an error on resolve intent constructor. But after I replace the this in the attachButtonListener with `MainActivity.this`, the error is just gone. I tried to read the Android documentation and it said that it should be a context in the Intent constructor.

Can anyone explain to me why I must use`MainActivity.this` instead of `this`? I am confused about what I am talking now as well. Is it because Context is not existing in this function and it exists in the `onCreate` function because the Context is created with `super.onCreate`?

Comment: `this` is referring to the anonymous implementation of the `View.OnClickListener` interface.

Answer (score 4):

And in the source:

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
  mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

`this` meant is`View.OnClickListener()`  in your code .

And we need `MainActivity.this` as `Context`

Change to this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent thePigeon = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
      thePigeon.putExtra(theString, theString);
    }
});
```

Comment: that's not what OP is interested in OP is interested in knowing " Can anyone explain to me why I must use MainActivity.this instead of this? "

Answer (score 1):

Intent constructor needs two parameters `Intent(context, class)`
and this keyword refers to **current** object.
So,

```
void attachButtonListener(Button btn, final String theString) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent thePigeon = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            thePigeon.putExtra(theString, theString);
        }
    });
}
```

in above intent `this` referring to the anonymous class of click listener which is not extended from Activity/Fragment cause of that this doesn't have context. So, if you do `MainActivity.this` this will refer to the MainActivity class which have context.

Answer (score 1):

> why I must use MainActivity.this instead of this?

The answer is scope.

"`this`" refers to the object where the method is executing.
The "context" for the new `intent` is provided by the `Activity`. 
But the place where the new intent is being created is inside an anonymous object of class `View.OnClickListener` which is enclosed in the Activity's instance.

From inside the anonymous object you can refer to the encolosing object's instace with "this" preceeded by the Class' name.
In this case `MainActivity.this`

In this way you get hold of the "context" you need to create the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Context:

**Application context** is associated with the application and will always be same throughout the life of application -- it does not change. So if you are using Toast, you can use application context or even activity context (both) because toast can be displayed from anywhere with in your application and is not attached to a specific window. But there are many exceptions, one exception is when you need to use or pass the activity context.

**Activity context** is associated with to the activity and can be destroyed if the activity is destroyed -- there may be multiple activities (more than likely) with a single application. And sometimes you absolutely need the activity context handle. For example, should you launch a new activity, you need to use activity context in its Intent so that the new launching activity is connected to the current activity in terms of activity stack. However, you may use application's context too to launch a new activity but then you need to set flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in intent to treat it as a new task.

Let's consider some cases:

`MainActivity.this` refers to the MainActivity context which extends Activity class but the base class (activity) also extends Context class, so it can be used to offer activity context.

`getBaseContext()` offers activity context.

`getApplication()` offers application context.

`getApplicationContext()` also offers application context.

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the current context if you use
`Intent thePigeonsss = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);`

Intent constructor needs context of your MainActivity so the above line works fine and if you want to use this in your onClickListner then the above line then `this` will point to `View.OnClickListener()` which the Intent constructor doesn't need so you have to specify MainActivity.this to point the reference the context of your MainActivity. So in your onClickListner you have to put this line

`Intent thePigeonsss = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);`

You have to specify to Intent constructor that take the context of MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the *current object* — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

When you using the following code:

```
void attachButtonListener(Button btn, final String theString) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent thePigeon = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            thePigeon.putExtra(theString, theString);
        }
    });
}
```

`this` will refer to `View.OnClickListener()` which is the object where the `this` reside.

So, you need to use MainActivity.this to refer the object of the MainActivity. You need to change your creation of intent with:

```
Intent thePigeon = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be used to refer current class instance variable.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Intent thePigeonsss = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
}
```

In above code, the `this` is referring to the main activity object so when you pass this in the parameter it belongs to main activity.

```
void attachButtonListener(Button btn, final String theString) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent thePigeon = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
          thePigeon.putExtra(theString, theString);
        }
    });
}
```

but when you use the this in the button click listener, this represents the current interface which does not have any context available and the compiler is generating the error but when you pass `MainActivity.this` it will get context from the activity class so the error is gone.

You can also use `view.getContext()` instead of `MainActivity.this` if you don't want to use MainActivity.this but it is better to use MainActivity.this for starting any new activity.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent thePigeon = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
      thePigeon.putExtra(theString, theString);

  }
});
```